Remove fields with minus from list in sed
The sed does not work as I expect
I work with
Linux pietro-Veriton-X2640G 5.15.0-122-generic #132~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 30 15:50:07 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I expect that
echo 'w=7 -o=... -w=8 -w=9 k=3 iop=0' | sed -e 's/ -[^ ]* / /g'

should destroy all blank-separate fields that start by minus and give
w=7 k=3 iop=0

but I get
w=7 -w=8 k=3 iop=0


You have overlapping matches, but each character can only be matched (and replaced) once:
echo 'w=7 -o=... -w=8 -w=9 k=3 iop=0' | sed -e 's/ -[^ ]* / /g'
         ^^^^^^^^
                ^^^^^^
                     ^^^^^^

Since your match ends with a space and you are replacing it with a space (and the repeated character set can not match the space), simply drop it from both patterns:
echo 'w=7 -o=... -w=8 -w=9 k=3 iop=0' | sed -e 's/ -[^ ]*//g'

Output:
w=7 k=3 iop=0


Thanks very much, especially because you have not done humorism on the title. May anyone suggest me a title that works?
